# Recursive function within an NDSolve is not updating

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The code below models a simple SIR model (used in disease control) in Mathematica. (I copied it directly from my notebook).

The equations can be solved using `NDSolve` and the solutions are inserted into three different functions for further use.

As can be seen the Beta term on the first line varies depending on the value of Inf[t], which is one of the three solutions of the `NDSolve` function.

This code works fine and I have included this in order to better explain my quesion below.

```
Beta = Piecewise[{{0.01, Inf[t] > 20}, {.06, Inf[t] <= 20}}];
Mu = 0.1;
Pop = 100;
ans = NDSolve[{S'[t] == -Beta S[t] Inf[t], 
    Inf'[t] == Beta S[t] Inf[t] - Mu Inf[t], 
    R'[t] == Mu Inf[t], 
    S[0] == Pop - 1, Inf[0] == 1, 
    R[0] == 0}, {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Sus[t_] = S[t] /. ans[[1, 1]];
Infected[t_] = Inf[t] /. ans[[1, 2]];
Rec[t_] = R[t] /. ans[[1, 3]];
```

I now wanted to update the code so that instead of having an either/or value for the `Beta` parameter based on the `Inf[t]` value, I would have the Beta value being equal to the output of a function where `Inf[t]` is the input. This can be seen below where `UpdateTransmission[]` is the function.

When I try and run the code below though the `Beta` value remains at 0 and does not increase. The problem is not with the `UpdateTransmission` function as I have tested this independently.

```
Beta = UpdateTransmission[SpinMatrix, ThresholdMatrix, Inf[t]];
Mu = 0.1;
Pop = 100;
ans = NDSolve[{S'[t] == -Beta S[t] Inf[t], 
    Inf'[t] == Beta S[t] Inf[t] - Mu Inf[t], 
    R'[t] == Mu Inf[t], S[0] == Pop - 1, Inf[0] == 1, 
    R[0] == 0}, 
    {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Sus[t_] = S[t] /. ans[[1, 1]];
Infected[t_] = Inf[t] /. ans[[1, 2]];
Rec[t_] = R[t] /. ans[[1, 3]];

Plot[{Sus[t], Infected[t], Rec[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this may not be running correctly?

Edit: here is the updated function

```
UpdateTransmission[S_, Th_, Infect_] := Module[{BetaOverall},
 P = S;
 For[i = 1, i <= Pop, i++,
    P[[i]] = Sign[Infect - Th[[i]]];];
   BetaOverall = ((Count[P, 1]*.02) + (Count[P, -1]*.5))/Pop
]
```

Here are the two lists that are referred to in the code above:

```
SpinMatrix = Table[-1, {Pop}]

val := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[.5, .1]]
ThresholdMatrix = Table[Pop*val, {Pop}]
```

**Edit Edit**

Ok I've put everything together and tried to plot my three curves. Now as can be seen here they are all flat-lining. The Sus[t] line is staying at 100 whilst the other two seem to be staying below 1. What should be happening here is that the Sus[t] line should drop considerably and the other two lines should ramp up.

(I tried to insert and image but I can't as I don't have the reputation points required so I'll just past in the code and you can see the plot yourself on your own machine)

```
 Pop = 100;
SpinMatrix = Table[-1, {Pop}];
val := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[.5, .1]];
ThresholdMatrix = Table[Pop*val, {Pop}];

updateTransmission[S_, Th_, Infect_] := Module[{}, P = S;
   For[i = 1, i <= Pop, i++, P[[i]] = Sign[Infect - Th[[i]]];];
   Return[((Count[P, 1]*.02) + (Count[P, -1]*.5))/Pop]];

beta[t_] := updateTransmission[SpinMatrix, ThresholdMatrix, Inf[t]];
mu = 0.1;
ans = NDSolve[{S'[t] == -beta[t] S[t] Inf[t], 
    Inf'[t] == beta[t] S[t] Inf[t] -
      mu Inf[t], R'[t] == mu Inf[t], S[0] == Pop - 1, Inf[0] == 1, 
    R[0] == 0}, {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Sus[t_] = S[t] /. First@ans;
Infected[t_] = Inf[t] /. First@ans;
Rec[t_] = R[t] /. First@ans;
Plot[{Sus[t], Infected[t], Rec[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

The output that I am expecting should look similar to that of the code given below:

```
Beta = Piecewise[{{0.5, Inf[t] > 20}, {.02, Inf[t] <= 20}}];
Mu = 0.1;
Pop = 100;
ans = NDSolve[{S'[t] == -Beta S[t] Inf[t], 
    Inf'[t] == Beta S[t] Inf[t] - Mu Inf[t], 
    R'[t] == Mu Inf[t], S[0] == Pop - 1, Inf[0] == 1, 
    R[0] == 0}, {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Sus[t_] = S[t] /. ans[[1, 1]];
Infected[t_] = Inf[t] /. ans[[1, 2]];
Rec[t_] = R[t] /. ans[[1, 3]];
Plot[{Sus[t], Infected[t], Rec[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: again, welcome to Stackoverflow. I formatted your code for readability by placing it in a code block and removing the Mathematica markup. I'd suggest learning to use markdown, the html engine used here to format posts. Above each question and answer text box is a question mark that details how to use markdown, and it is quite extensive. Also, internally Mathematica represents the character, beta, with `\[Beta]`, and the internal version is what is copied. For readability, the mark up should be removed.

Comment: I should note a trade off here, `Beta` is a reserved word in Mathematica, but `\[Beta]` is not. So, the above code is not directly executable any longer, and I don't think the veteran members have come to a consensus on exactly what needs to be done. My thinking is that the mark-up should be removed and the symbols made lower case. Any one else have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I'll try that out in my future questions

Comment: Ok thanks for that advice. I have tried voting up answers but I am unable to as my total is too low for the time being. I certainly hope that I can answer other people's questions as my own knowledge grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The culprit is Sign[ ]

I don't know why, but I traced the problem to the Sign[ ] function that is not working properly inside NDSolve!

Removing it:

```
Pop = 100;
SpinMatrix = Table[-1, {Pop}];
val := RandomReal[NormalDistribution[.5, .1]];

ThresholdMatrix = Table[Pop*val, {Pop}];

updateTransmission[Th_, Inf_] :=
  Total[Table[If[Inf >= Th[[i]], 2/100, 1/2]/Pop , {i, Pop}]];

beta[t_] := updateTransmission[ThresholdMatrix, Inf[t]];
mu = 0.1;

ans = NDSolve[{
    S'[t] == -beta[t] S[t] Inf[t],
    Inf'[t] == beta[t] S[t] Inf[t] - mu Inf[t],
    R'[t] == mu Inf[t],
    S[0] == Pop - 1,
    R[0] == 0,
    Inf[0] == 1}, {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Sus[t_] = S[t] /. First@ans;
Infected[t_] = Inf[t] /. First@ans;
Rec[t_] := R[t] /. First@ans;
Plot[{Sus[t], Infected[t], Rec[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Gives:

[image]

Probably someone with better knowledge of Mma could explain what is happening in your code.

HTH!

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. What I'm trying to output is a graph of the 3 functions at the end versus time. When I do this though I get three flatlines which is a result of the fact that my Beta value is not updating (staying at 0). I've tried making Beta into a function like you have done above but it didn't change things.

Comment: @Sperick, using the definition of `updateTransmission` above in `beta = updateTransmission[ Inf[t] ]`, I get the same result as belisarius. Could you post the definition of `UpdateTransmission` as belisarius's operates by replacing `updateTransmission[ Inf[t] ]` with `2 Inf[t] + 1.`, which remains unevaluated as I noted in my answer. This implies that your definition is interpreting `Inf[t]` as having a value, when it should just leave it unevaluated.

Comment: Ok-I simplified UpdateTransmission in order to make the question less complicated. It is in fact a Module but hopefully that shouldn't make too much of a difference. Here it is (is the comment the best place to do this by the way? I can't seem to start new paragraphs)              UpdateTransmission[S_, Th_, Infect_] := Module[{\[Beta]Overall},
  P = S;
  For[i = 1, i <= Pop, i++,
   P[[i]] = Sign[Infect - Th[[i]]];];
  \[Beta]Overall = ((Count[P, 1]*.02) + (Count[P, -1]*.5))/Pop
  ]

Comment: @Sperick Please post that code as an update to your question (click on **Edit** below the question), so you can format it properly

Comment: Hi belisarius-I've updated my original post to show you exactly what I'm getting. I'm not actually interested in plotting beta but I am interested in plotting functions that are dependent on beta changing. See above and thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: Hi again. It's not just a question of scale (which is what i presume you mean when you say to plot them on different graphs). I've updated my original post again and attached some code at the bottom. The output of that code is something similar to what I am hoping for in the other code. Thanks

Comment: That is strange but it's good to know where the problem was. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In some ways, you are encountering the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html?q=Set&lang=en) (`=`) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html?q=SetDelayed&lang=en) (`:=`).  For instance, if you wrote `f = 7`, `f` becomes `7` in all occurrences of `f` after it was initialized. But, if you wrote `f = 7 t` instead, and tried to use it as you would a function, i.e. `f[8]`, you'd get `(7 t)[8]` because `Set` says that the value of `f` is unchanging.  `SetDelayed`, however, implies that the value of `f` will change and must be reevaluated every time it occurs. Your initial case, though, is special.

When you wrote

```
Beta = Piecewise[{{0.01, Inf[t] > 20}, {.06, Inf[t] <= 20}}]
```

`Inf[t]` was undefined, so that it remained unevaluated.  But, every occurence of `Beta` in your differential equations was replaced by the above formula, courtesy of `Set`, so `NDSolve` only saw the `Piecewise` functions.  In your second case, you wrote

```
Beta = UpdateTransmission[Inf[t]]
```

Here the problem is that `UpdateTransmission` is executed only when `Beta` is initially defined, and while `Piecewise` remains unevaluated, `UpdateTransmission` most likely still gives a result for a purely symbolic input. I'd try one of three things,

1. replace every occurrence of `Beta` in you equations with `UpdateTransmission[Inf[t]]`,
2. redefine `Beta` using `SetDelayed`, e.g.

   ```
   Beta := UpdateTransmission[Inf[t]]
   ```

   so that it will be reevaluated every time it is encountered, or
3. redefine `UpdateTransmission` to not accept symbols via either

   ```
   UpdateTransmission[x_?(Head[#]=!=Symbol&)] := ...
   ```

   or

   ```
   UpdateTransmission[x_] /; Head[x]=!= Symbol := ...
   ```

Option 3 works by forcing `UpdateTransmission[Inf[t]]` to remain unevaluated, and effectively does the same thing as option 1. But, it requires a minimum of change. Personally, I'm in favor of options 1 or 3, as I don't know how many times `Beta` will need to be reevaluated as `NDSolve` operates.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and interesting reply. I have tried each of the three suggestions but I'm still getting the same output as I did before. As I said in my reply to the other person who answered I'm trying to plot a graph of the three functions at the end of the code versus time. I would expect them to vary (the Sus[t] should begin at 100 and drop down and the other two should start at 0 and 1 and rise up). Instead they are all stayin in their initial states as a result of the Beta values remaining at zero

Comment: @sperick, I replied to you on belisarius' answer. But, this brings up an interesting point: with `beta = 0`, `Infected` should be a decaying exponential, `Exp[-0.1 t]`. Plotting `Sus[t]` in a `LogPlot` between 0 and 0.1, shows that it falls off extremely rapidly (using Belisarius' def below), as it is below `10^-8` by `t = 0.01`. However, the inability to see the decay (rise) of `Infected` (`Rec`) implies something else is going on. Have you tried quitting the kernel and restarting?